# How to create custom list filters based on month and year in Django admin

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model which has a date field and I want to create a list filter which will show the following options,

> Current
>
> 2017
>
> 2016
>
> 2015

upon clicking on the year link it will collapse into the months as,

> 2017
>
> 01
>
> 02
>
> 03
>
> 04 ...

I tried the default `DateFieldListFilter` but it has only the following options,

> Any
>
> Today
>
> Past 7 days
>
> This month
>
> This year

I was trying to solve this using `SimpleListFilter` but could not succeed.

```
class MonthFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'Month'
    parameter_name = 'month'
    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        months = [["current", "Current"]]
        qs = model_admin.model.objects.exclude(ts_from=None).order_by('ts_from')
        last= qs[0]
        last_year = last.ts_from.year
        current = timezone.now()
        current_year = current.year
        months.append([current_year, current_year])
        months.append([last_year, last_year])
        return months

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():
            return queryset.filter(ts_from__contains=self.value())
        else:
            return queryset
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you didn't filter yet with month in queryset

```
def queryset(self, request, queryset):
    month = request.GET.get('month') or datetime.now().month
    if self.value():
        return queryset.filter(ts_from__contains=self.value(), created__month=month)
    else:
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

I made 2 filters one for year and the other one for month:

```py
class YearFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    title = _("Year")
    parameter_name = _("year")

    def lookups(self, request: HttpRequest, model_admin: ModelAdmin) -> list:
        qs = model_admin.model.objects.exclude(ts_from=None).order_by(
            "ts_from"
        )
        first_year = qs[0].ts_from.year
        current_year = datetime.now().year
        return [(y, y) for y in range(first_year, current_year + 1)]

    def queryset(self, request: HttpRequest, queryset: QuerySet) -> QuerySet:
        if self.value():
            return queryset.filter(ts_from__year=self.value())
        else:
            return queryset


class MonthFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    title = _("Month")
    parameter_name = _("month")

    def lookups(self, request: HttpRequest, model_admin: ModelAdmin) -> list:
        return [(m, m) for m in range(1, 13)]

    def queryset(self, request: HttpRequest, queryset: QuerySet) -> QuerySet:
        if self.value():
            return queryset.filter(ts_from__month=self.value())
        else:
            return queryset
```

it is not ideal as a solution but I guess better than installing a package to filter just per month

result (it is showing only 2020 as I do not have any data in 2019:
[image: example of filter in wagtail]